# Npgsql F# Parameterized Queries

Tags: .net, f#, npgsql

I'm attempting to use Npgsql parametrized queries in FSharp but I am unable to properly get Npgsql to update the parameter value. Sample code looks as follows:

```
let ins_command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE keyid = :keyid")
ins_command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("keyid", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)) |> ignore
for key in keys do
    ins_command.Parameters.["keyid"].Value = (box key)
    ins_command.ExecuteScalar())
```

The "keyid" parameter is always set to null and when viewed as a watch variable it's never set. Without using `AddWithValue` how can I set these parameters properly in FSharp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the library, but the line

```
ins_command.Parameters.["keyid"].Value = (box key)
```

looks like it is doing nothing. Unless the `=` operator has been changed, this is only a test for equality. It *should* give a compiler warning, as a check for equality is of type `bool` and this line doesn't do anything with the result.

If you want to use a property setter (or assign to a mutable value), use the operator `<-`

Comment: Hi Vandroiy, +1 for the idea. I think this was a newbie FSharp mistake given the pervasiveness of = being used in various places but not others.